# Learning graphical design as a developer

Tags: design, websites, graphics

I'm mostly a developer and have been offered a job as webmaster. It's likely that I'll be asked to make some cosmetic changes to a website every now and then.

Has anyone made this transition? If so, how did things go? Also, are there any good online sources to get up to speed on how things are done today?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Anna. I sometimes get the spelling mixed up between "developer" in English and "développeur" in French.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick up [The Non-Designers Design Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1566091594) and [The Non-Designer's Web Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321303377) by Robin Williams. It's a great place to start.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's very important for a developer to get atleast a basic knowledge of design principles.

1. Search on google for "design web 2.0" - the first link there is very good.
2. Download a tool called "colorcop" (if you're on windows). It's a life saver.
3. Know how to use the main programs in Adobe creative suite. Especially Adobe Fireworks, Adobe Illustrator, Adobe Photoshop. Know the difference between a vector and a bitmap and when to use either one (this is key).
4. Use Lynda.com to learn 3.

Comment: +1 for lynda . If you work on flash even though you might be a programmer you are expected to know and do( at times or always depending on where you work) every thing a graphic design artist/animator does.

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend [Principles of Beautiful Web Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0975841963). It's a design book for non-designers. The Author covers the golden ratio, color schemes, the importance of fonts, composition, etc.

As for design software, a little training/knowledge goes a LONG way with Photoshop/Illustrator. Follow a few basic tutorials, then search for specific tutorials as you need them.

Answer (score 2):

Believe me I was a pure programmer. I believed i had no aesthetic skills. Until one fine day I decided to start my own freelance business. Initially I had planned to do the programming myself and outsource the design to someone I knew. It was bad, real bad. The designer kept me waiting for the design and I would have to keep my client waiting. Until one night an elderly person advised me to do the designing myself. I told him but I don't design. He insisted. He asked me to go home pray to Allah and start designing. That night I came back home, prayed to Allah and yeah I made my first website design. I mailed the design to my client late night guess what? Next morning he accepted the design! Thats how I got into designing. I did know about basic editing, cropping etc. in Photoshop. But yeah Allah helped me. So its not impossible.